# webchat integration with Atlassian Confluence

Tags: botframework, web-chat

Has anyone integrated the webchat/directline from Microsoft Botframework with Atlassian Confluence
We are exploring options to host a chatbot on one of the wikis powered by Confluence

Any directions/guidance will help;

Answer (score 0):

The only option I see is to use the "/" (slash) command and add an embedded iframe into the space's page. It's possible to backup and download, edit, and upload and restore a page however, the exported page is in XML. So, editing a backed up page wouldn't give you access to the HTML needed to truly integrate Web Chat into the page.

As for the slash command, you will need to develop a separate web app to host the Web Chat instance. Then, simply provide the values required in the iframe macro tool, and you should be set.

iframe macro:
[image]

Published page:
[image]

Hope of help!